# how to check if user has full control permissions on a shared folder?

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5, permissions, wmi

I use the following code in order to check if certin user exists in  the `DACL`:

```
Dim l_managemantObject As ManagementBaseObject() = CType(securityDescriptor.Properties("DACL").Value, ManagementBaseObject())

For Each mObject As ManagementBaseObject In l_managemantObject
    l_name = CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Name").Value.ToString
    If CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Domain").Value IsNot Nothing Then
       l_domain = CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Domain").Value.ToString()
    End If

    If users.UserName.ToLower = (l_domain & "\" & l_name).ToLower Then
       Return True                
    End If
Next
```

As you can see, I'm able to get the username and domain. But how do I check if the user has `FullControl` permissions?

**Edit:**

I've done furthur investigation and found that using `GetAccessMask`, I can retrieve the access rights to the share held by the user or group on whose behalf the instance is returned.

So whats left to find out is:
**How to get a specific user `AccessMask`?**

[AccessMask on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390438)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was under my nose all the time, using `GetPropertyValue("AccessMask")` on the managementObject gets the permission level.

**Full method:**

```
 Dim l_managemantObject As ManagementBaseObject() = CType(securityDescriptor.Properties("DACL").Value, ManagementBaseObject())

    For Each mObject As ManagementBaseObject In l_managemantObject
        l_name = CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Name").Value.ToString
        If CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Domain").Value IsNot Nothing Then
           l_domain = CType(mObject.GetPropertyValue("Trustee"), ManagementBaseObject).Properties("Domain").Value.ToString()
        End If

        Dim l_accessMask as UInteger = mObject.GetPropertyValue("AccessMask")

        If users.UserName.ToLower = (l_domain & "\" & l_name).ToLower Then
           if l_accessMask = 2032127 then
              Return True  
           endif                             
        End If
    Next
```